# dynamic width spacer in CSS horizontal menu

Tags: css, menu

I've got a simple horizontal menu (see below).  Some of the items are floated left and some are floated right (those to the right are admin options and appear on every page, while those on the left are context specific.  Each menu item has borders that make them appear as raised buttons.  I'd like a spacer item between the left and right floated items that is also styled as a raised button.

My problem is that I can't figure out how (in a pure CSS way, represented by the "ul.menu li.spacer" selector in the CSS below) to make the spacer's width stretch to fill the available space between the left and right floated items.  The spacer's width will be different depending on the context since the number and widths of the other items varies depending on context.

I could write some javascript to dynamically set the spacer's width, but that would have to be browser specific, since different browsers treat borders/margins differently and I don't want to have to do that, and would get REALLY ugly.

[Note that the floated right items are listed in reverse order they will appear on the screen, because of the float right]

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Item One</a></li>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Item Two</a></li>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Item Three</a></li>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Item Four</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Item Eight</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Item Seven</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Item Six</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Item Five</a></li>
    <li class='spacer'><a href='#'>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is my CSS

```
ul.menu {
    width: 100% ;
    list-style: none ;
    height: 2em ;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0 ;
    }
ul.menu li.left {
    float: left ;
    }
ul.menu li.right {
    float: right ;
    display: inline-block ;
    }
ul.menu li {
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: #fff #000 #000 #fff ;
    position: relative ;
    text-align: center ;
    vertical-align: middle ;
    }
ul.menu li a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    }
ul.menu li.spacer {
    width: ??? ;
    }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJCAX/1/

Comment: scott: what is the "fiddle" you added?  I don't understand it

Comment: It's your code added to a site that people can "fiddle" with the code to try to get the effect you want.

Comment: thanx, I'd hadn't seen that before.  useful

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking a rather complicated approach. If you make two different lists it would be much simpler, no spacer needed.

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Ar3DH/3/

**html**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="user">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="admin">
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

**css:**

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 40px;
    font: bold 15px/40px Arial;
}
#admin {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
li { float: left; }
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
​
```

Comment: eclanrs: if it weren't for the "raised button" look of each menu item, perhaps you'd be right.  But that is the crux of my problem.  With the "raised button" styling of the individual menu items, it looks strange to have the "flat" space between the 2 sets of menu items.

Comment: Well, it's possible, you just have to work on it... http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Ar3DH/3/

Comment: thanx, with a combination of what you've done in your fiddle and what Scott suggested below I think I've cobbled together something that works.  I've still got a bit of testing to do and I'm tired so I'll report on those test results tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This uses borders on the `ul` and some pseudo-elements to achieve the effect. See this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJCAX/26/. I've noticed, however, that Firefox occasionally mis-displays the left border of the middle space (rendering bug apparently). Also note that if the right buttons "wrap" down to the next level (narrow screen) the effect is broken.

Here's the code (added two `last` classes):

**HTML**

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>One</a></li>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Two</a></li>
    <li class='left'><a href='xxx'>Three</a></li>
    <li class='left last'><a href='xxx'>Four</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Eight</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'>Seven</a></li>
    <li class='right'><a href='xxx'> Six</a></li>
    <li class='right last'><a href='xxx'>Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.menu {
    width: 100% ;
    list-style: none ;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0 ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    }
ul.menu li.left {
    float: left ;
    }
ul.menu li.right {
    float: right ;
    display: inline-block ;
    }
ul.menu li {
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: #fff #000 #000 #fff ;
    position: relative ;
    text-align: center ;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: -1px 0;
    }
ul.menu li a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    }
ul.menu li.right.last:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
ul.menu li.left.last:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }
```

Comment: thanx, see my comments to Cedric above.

Comment: using Cedric's 2 separate lists and your :before/:after trick basically works.  I got a few more tweaks to do (and won't have time to get to those for a few days), but I will definitely post the final results when I'm done.  Thanx again!